# Substitution in conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory

A paper I'm reading does something like the following:

Random variable $Y$ has the property that $E[e^{mY} \mid X] \leq 1$ for all $m\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence it is claimed that $E[e^{XY}] \leq 1$. How is this justified? What property of conditional expectation allows this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By tower property,
$$
E(e^{XY}) = E(E(e^{XY} \mid X)) \leq1
$$
Since $E(X) \leq a$ if $X\leq a$